# What happens to iron(III) sulfate (ferric sulfate) in aqueous solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, ions

[Iron(II) sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron%28II%29_sulfate) (ferrous sulfate) is a salt that, in an aqueous solution, dissolves and yields $\ce{Fe^{2+}(aq)}$ and $\ce{SO4^{2-}(aq)}$. It then [decomposes to ferric sulfate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31243/what-is-formed-when-you-leave-iron-ii-sulfate-in-plain-air) shortly thereafter.

But what happens to the [iron(III) sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron%28III%29_sulfate) (ferric sulfate) in solution? Is the $\ce{Fe_2(SO_4)_3}$ compound preserved?

Comment: Fe2+ is oxidated by oxygen, Fe3+ can't be ox. this way.

Comment: Are you asking whether the ferric sulphate dissociates in solution into separate ions?

Comment: @bon yes. Or maybe some kind of reaction takes place?

Comment: Well hydrolysis may take place

Answer (score 5):

In aqueous solution $\ce{Fe2(SO4)3}$ dissociates into $\ce{Fe^{3+} (aq)}$ and $\ce{SO4^{2-} (aq)}$ ions. The sulphate ions will be solvated by hydrogen bonding with the water and the iron ions will form the hexaaquairon(III) complex, $\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^{3+}}$.

As @Mithoron mentioned, the $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ ions cannot easily be further oxidised so no additional reaction takes place.